# How to get Internet Explorer 8.0.7601?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I need to test some reports on IE 8.0.7601. We cannot use any other latest version but only this particular version.

I read somewhere that IE 8.0.7601 is not available for download but it is IE 8 installed on Windows 7 Service Pack 1. I have IE 9 installed on my Win 7 Service Pack 1 system. I uninstalled IE 9, downloaded and installed IE 8 on my system but still I do not get the required version.

Can someone please guide me on how to get this version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install this:
Internet Explorer 8.0.7601.17514IC
http://www.oldversion.com/windows/internet-explorer-8-0-7601-17514ic

Answer (score -1):

If you are using other browser, you can find an add-on which provides a compatibility for IE8 , Go to Add-ons in your browser and search for IE Add-on..

Comment: I need to verify Business objects reports using web portal InfoView using IE 8.0.7601. That is the reason why I need this particular version. With add-on I wont be able to get this particular version.